# RescorerProvider filter element by tag

Tags: myrrix

Is it possible to create a RescorerProvider to filter out elements which are associated with a specific tag? Or should I implement an own model with relevant data as in the book "mahout in action" on page 79?

Route: /recommend/?rescorerParams=sports
Push score of elements which are associated with tag sports

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you would have to separately track which items are associated to which tags. This information is not queryable within the server itself. But you can periodically cache this info from an external source and then apply whatever logic you like based on tags. Yes, it is kind of like what's in Mahout in Action.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! Your book mahout in action helped me so much!